# Understanding $O$-notation and the meaning of $\Omega$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am studying algorithms, and I have problems on the concepts from an exercise. Thank you so much!

> Which of the following equations lie in $O(n)$, $\Omega(n)$, $\Theta(n)$ and why.
>
> a. $3n+2n^2$
>
> b. $\log {n}+4n^3+6n$
>
> c. $5n+6$

My answer:
$O(n)$: c only
$\Omega(n)$: a only
$\Theta(n)$: c only

But the answers are saying:
$O(n)$: c only
$\Omega(n)$: a, b, c
$\Theta(n)$: c only

I am confused. Doesn't $\Omega$ mean a lower bound on the equation? Then the $\Omega$ of $a, b, c$ should be:
a: $\Omega(n)$
b: $\Omega(\log n) \leftarrow \Omega(\log n)$ should be lower than $\Omega(n)$
c: $\Omega(1) \leftarrow$ much lower than $\Omega(n)$

Comment: _Why_ do you think those are the answers? You'll want to make sure you are giving the right answers for the right reasons, not just by random luck.

Comment: You should always look for the dominating terms for  $O$ , $\Theta$ and $\Omega$ .In polynomials, it will have the one with largest degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot the functions...  It will make it a lot clearer.  $\Omega (n)$ means that the function $f(n)$ (for large enough $n$) will take on values such that $f(n) > cn$, where $c$ is some constant.

For plot examples, look here:

> [Problem A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%283n%2b2n%5E2,%20n%29%20from%200%20to%2010) (Obviously here, $f(n) \gg n$)
>
> [Problem B](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28log%20n%2b4n%5E3%2b6n,%20n%29%20from%200%20to%202) (Again, for large enough $n$, $f(n) \gg n$)
>
> [Problem C](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%285n%2b6,%20n%29%20from%200%20to%202) (For all $n$, $f(n) \gt n$)

EDIT: Note that $\Omega$ notation is not specifying the term in $f(n)$ that grows the slowest, but rather *any function* that grows slower than the *entirety* of $f(n)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot! it's much clearer from the graph!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know $O$ :

If $f(n)=O(g(n)) $ then  $g(n)=\Omega(f(n) )  $.

And $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$  $ \iff $ $f(n)=O(g(n))$  and  $f(n)=\Omega(g(n)) $  .

So  $\Theta $  gives a tight bound.

$O$  gives an upper bound.

$\Omega $ gives a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the function is $\Theta (g(n))$ iff it is both $O(g(n))$ and $\Omega(g(n))$. Hence the answer to (c).