# What notation is used for the canonical representation of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I've looked on Math.SE and Wikipedia so far and found nothing.  I thought I found what I was looking for, but it turned out to be Euler's Totient function.

Taking the canonical representation of an integer $n$:

$$n=p_0^{a_0}\cdot p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$$

Is there a standard notation for $\sum_{i=0}^r a_r$?  Are there any known theorems dealing directly with this quantity aside from those dealing with the Totient function?  Thank you!

Comment: It's $\Omega(n)$, the number of all prime factors of $n$, in contrast to $\omega(n)$, which is the number of _distinct_ prime divisors of $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: perfect, thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer: wait a moment though, how does this usage relate to the one shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310820/understanding-o-notation-and-the-meaning-of-omega)?

Comment: As for a theorem dealing with it, the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the statement $\sum_{k \le n}{(-1)^{\Omega(k)}} = O(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Comment: @abiessu Not related. The same symbol used for different things.

Comment: @abiessu those are completely different $\Omega$s.  But in my last comment I mixed the two notations (the $O$ I used is a big-oh, and the $\Omega$ is the number of prime factors).

Comment: Got it, thanks all!

Comment: @DanBrumleve One should find some interesting result that is true iff $\Omega(n)$ is $\Omega(whatever)$ XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments provided the requested notation accurately, namely, that if we have

$$n=p_0^{a_0}\cdot p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}\tag 1$$

then we use $\Omega(n)=\sum_{i=0}^ra_i$ to denote the count of prime factors of $n$ including multiplicity.  I believe I have even found a reasonable arithmetic function composition that can be used to "calculate" $\Omega(n)$ for any given $n$, although I introduce a "new" function (which can probably best be considered an "anti-derivative" of an existing function) in order to arrive at this information.

To begin, note that the Mangoldt function is defined as

$$\Lambda(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\log p & \text{if $n=p^k$ for prime $p$ and integer $k$}\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Now branch our "new" function from here as the arithmetic "anti-derivative" of the Mangoldt function, which is to say that the Mangoldt function will be the arithmetic derivative of our function:

$$\eth(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\log_np=\frac 1k & \text{if $n=p^k$ for prime $p$ and integer $k$}\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Now the sum over the distinct prime divisors of $n$ works like this:

$$\omega(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\eth(d)$$

Getting $\Omega(n)$ is a little trickier, since we have $\eth(p^k)=\frac 1k$ for primes $p$ when we actually want $1$ for each of these values.  But this can be solved with multiplication by another sum:

$$\Omega(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\left(\mu(d)\eth(d)\sum_{d^k\mid n}1\right)$$

Using our definition, we can ask some questions about our function; for instance:

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\eth(d)=\sum_{i=0}^rH_{a_i}$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$th Harmonic Number, being the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1i$.  This is slightly counter-intuitive when we consider that $\log n=\sum_{d\mid n}\Lambda(d)$ and that $\eth(n)={\Lambda(n) \over \log n}$.